# Backup nginx server returning 504

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have 3 nginx servers setup. The backup web server and the Home server both have identical `../sites-enabled` and `../sites-available` directories. And the third server acts as a load balancer that points to both the backup and the home server with the config:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 1.1.1.1; #home server
    server 2.2.2.2 backup; #backup server
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

But I am having an issue (which is explained more graphically below) when I am testing to see whether the backup server is working, as it only seems to be working when the Home Server is on!

```
1. test.foo.com -> Backup Web Server
2. foo.com       -> Load Balancer
3. www.foo.com   -> Home server
```

`->` means *points to*

When Nothing is down:

```
- 1 returns OK
- 2 returns OK
- 3 returns OK
```

When Home Server is down:

```
- 1 returns 504 **(SHOULD BE OK)**
- 2 returns 504 **(SHOULD BE OK)**
- 3 returns DNS error
```

When Load Balancer is down:

```
- 1 returns OK
- 2 returns DNS error
- 3 returns OK
```

When Backup Web Server is down:

```
- 1 returns DNS error
- 2 returns 200
- 3 returns 200
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused on the terminology here:

- when load balancer is down, you'd be getting [`connect(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/connect.2) [`Connection refused`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/errno.h#ECONNREFUSED) or [`Operation timed out`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/errno.h#ETIMEDOUT)-style errors; you would not be getting DNS errors
- likewise, the fact that you're getting `504` from your upstream home server, means that it is NOT down, thus your backup server never gets used, because `nginx` would only use `backup` if the primary server is really not available

You could potentially fix the second issue by getting the paid version of nginx, which has support for the [`health_check`](http://nginx.org/r/health_check) directive.

Alternatively, you could implement caching, and use [`proxy_cache_use_stale`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_use_stale) to specify that a cached version should be returned instead.  Also, take a look at [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page), too